# Relationship between commonality/rarity and synonymy

Tags: synonymy

Is there are term in linguistics for the phenomenon that there are a greater number of ways to express common, basic, and more frequently used concepts than there are ways to express concepts that are more rarely employed?

For example, there are a myriad of synonyms for "[big](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/big)" and a wide variety of ways to express this concept. There are significantly fewer ways to express "[curvaceous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/curvaceous)" and far fewer synonyms.

If there is no actual term for this phenomenon, is there are branch of research in linguistics that discusses this?

Comment: What makes you think "big" has more synonyms than "curvaceous"? )))

Comment: Big: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/big
Curvaceous: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/curvaceous

Comment: But big is also **polysemous** (the linked dictionary entry lists eight senses), whereas curvaceous has only one meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by 'frequently used concepts' though? There is no such thing as true synonymy in natural language, since all words have different distributions. For example, 'tremendous' and 'gigantic' are all listed as synonyms of 'big', but you are much more likely to say 'tremendous impact' than 'gigantic impact'.

Comment: I'm not aware of existing work on the topic but I guess you could slightly modify the question thus: If a part of a semantic space is more commonly mentioned, then words are more densely clustered there. Since semantic distance can be easily operationalised, so can density. so If we can operationalise the commonness of a semantic space, then perhaps this question can be investigated...

Comment: (Note: Of course, 'true synonymy' can occur in technical language, e.g. Riemann-integrable and Darboux-integrable are the same thing since one property implies the other. But you know what I mean :P)